# Multi module Android project cannot find Kotlin classes between modules

Tags: android, maven, gradle, kotlin

My environment is:

- Android Studio 3.3
- Gradle Plugin: 3.2.0
- Gradle version: 4.10.1
- Kotlin 1.2.71 (I've also tried 1.3.10)

The codebase is split across two git repos.  There's the core repo and then the main repo.  Module A lives in the core repo as a library, is compiled to an AAR, and published via maven.  It contains Kotlin code with `typealias`es and extensions.  It compiles fine and when I analyze the AAR in Android Studio, the classes.jar file shows the class with typealiases, class files, etc. intact.

Then, I have a module B in the main repo.  It has a Kotlin Activity class that uses several Kotlin classes from module A.

When I to try to compile the code, I get unresolved references to some of the typealiases and classes.

NOTE #1: before moving module A to the core repo (as part of a refactor of the app), it all compiled together in the main repo with no issues.

NOTE #2: other modules in the core repo are compiled to AARs, uploaded to an internal maven repo, and correctly pulled down and compiled by module B.  So, it's not the maven pipeline as far as I can tell.

NOTE #3: I have the following lines applied in each module:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${app.kotlinVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:${app.kotlinVersion}"
    kapt "androidx.databinding:databinding-compiler:${app.androidPluginVersion}"
}

apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.extensions'
androidExtensions {
    experimental = true
}
```

If I move the relevant package from module A to module B, then it compiles fine.  But, the relevant package is used across many modules, so I can't leave it in module B.

Any ideas on why I'm getting these unresolved reference errors during compile?

Comment: this problem just happen when you try to compile your application?

Comment: It's a new problem as of this week when we moved module A to the core git repo from the main git repo.

Comment: We had a workaround to make the code compile, but that broke a feature in the app, so now we either revert the move or find another fix.  But, long term, we need to NOT revert the move, so I need to find another fix :-/

Comment: I can't see the AAR dependency in the build.gradle you posted.

Comment: @m0skit0 That's only a partial gradle implementation.  We have a very custom gradle + groovy setup that would be too big (and proprietary) to post here.  But trust me, it's there.

Comment: Did you try compiling with `--refresh-dependencies`?

Comment: Yep, and no luck :-(

Comment: Ever find an answer to this?